# How can I load a .sql file when running a Maven/Hibernate project?

Tags: sql, hibernate, maven

I am using  hbm2ddl to create my tables and it works just fine but I also want hibernate to load a .sql file to populate the database each time I run my project.
I found that Hibernate should do this if my .sql file is in the classpath but it doesn't seem to work.

I am not sure if the file is in the classpath and I dont know how to find that out.
Currently my load.sql is in Other Sources/csr/main/resources/

I googled and read that I could add a file to te class path in the properties/libraries menu of my project but it seems Maven project doesn't have that section.

I am using Mysql with JDBC and Netbeans 7.1.2.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I am curious why you would want to rebuild your DB every time you run the app.

Comment: Sounds more like testing in this case but i'm not sure...

Comment: @foampile Example: We have a development configuration which does this (because developers tend to corrupt data hehe). Of course the configuration for the live system does not rebuild the database.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify which SQL file you want to load in your hibernate.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ... some other stuff comes here     
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">
            /import1.sql, /import2.sql
        </property>
    </session-factory>
<hibernate-configuration>
```

The script is only loaded if hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop. The import files are ignored on all other options
Note that only single line statements are allowed in this file.

Those two properties are described in the [Hibernate Configuration, Chapter 3.4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)

Comment: Script is also loaded if `hbm2ddl.auto=create`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sql-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) to do such things. This can run sql scripts etc. The hbm2ddl creates SQL scripts which can be executed by sql-maven-plugin.