# Hibernate automatic schema generation and extra tables

Tags: hibernate, schema

In my jUnit test hibernate creates the schema, and I have a import.sql to insert test data. 
Hibernate will of course only create tables from the JPA objects. 
I would like to create some extra tables when I run my JUnit test. Tables that do not have a JPA object.

I tryied to put create statements in the import.sql but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path to your `import.sql` file as `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property in Hibernate configuration file? If you have specified this path and still doesn't works, make sure it's referring to a correct path of your `import.sql` file. I Think there could be a typo or something like that

Edit:

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628614/how-can-i-load-a-sql-file-when-running-a-maven-hibernate-project) post:

> The script is only loaded if hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop. The import
>   files are ignored on all other options. Note that only single line
>   statements are allowed in this file.

Comment: The import.sql is loaded... all the insert statements are executed.
But my create table statements are not.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed at first. You can just specify DML statements (like insert, delete or update) in the file. It seems that you can't use it to create a new table

Comment: Why are you trying to create these tables for your unit tests? They are temporary?

Comment: The tables are history tables to the original tabled. I and would like Junit test on that.. validate that data get moved to history tables on delete and update operations.

Comment: Have you ever tried [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)? It's just for unit testing db operations and let you insert/delete data before/after each test case or test suite. Maybe helps you or give you some idea

Comment: I am trying to use DBUnit, but some places I read that it can not create tables, only fill data in them.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to just create the required tables which are not mapped to hibernate objects before running the test case.

How are you executing the import.sql? If you have the required access at the database level, you could create tables from java as hibernate does

Comment: import.sql is run by hibernate automatically. Here I have insert statements for test data and that works fine.